# Apache Storm : Relation between Executors ,Execute latency and Process latency?

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, apache-storm, metrics

**Topology with 1 executor assigned to Query Normalizer**
[image: Topology with 1 executor assigned to Query Normalizer]

**Topology with 4 executor assigned to Query Normalizer**
[image: Topology with 4 executor assigned to Query Normalizer]

Initially I was running my topology with only **1** executor assigned to QueryNormalizer. The **execute latency** was **8.952** and **process latency** was **12.857**.

To make it faster I changed the number of executors in QueryNormalizer to **4**.The **execute latency** changed to **197.616** and **process latency** to **59.132**.

According to the definition of **Execute latency** – The average time a Tuple spends in the execute method. The execute method may complete without sending an Ack for the tuple.

So, What I understand is it should be low if I increase the number of executors.As the parallelism should increase as the executor increases.

Am I misinterpreting something ?

Also, there is a huge difference between the emitted,transmitted and executed fields. Is this normal ?

Also, Should process latency be always lower than the execute latency ?

Which of the above shown topologies are better performance wise ? Also, How should I decide which topology is running better than the other , seeing the bolts data ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at "complete latency" in the spout, that is the value the tuples spend in average inside in your topology, it had decreed.

> So, What I understand is it should be low if I increase the number of executors.As the parallelism should increase as the executor increases.

it means you have now 4 units processing tuples, each unit process 1 tuple at the time, "theoretically" let you process 4 tuples at the same time instead of 1. Do your tuples look always the the same? this is, do they have always the same complexity?

> ```
> Also, there is a huge difference between the emitted,transmitted and executed fields. Is this normal ?
> ```

executed means how many tuples your bolt consumed; emitted means how many tuples your bolt generated (in your case i see each consumed tuple is generating around 4 new tuples); transfered means how many emitted tuples were transfered to other bolts, for example you have two bolts consuming from the bolt emitting, in this case transfered would be equal a 2 * nr of tuples emitted.

> Also, Should process latency be always lower than the execute latency ?

Not necessaly, have for example at [Nathan Marz](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/storm-user/execute$20and$20latency/storm-user/3OpJGdZ25ss/gC0cWtQ8rCkJ) definition:

```
Process latency is time until tuple is acked, execute latency is time spent in execute for a tuple
```

and I can give you an example of one of my topologies where this does not happen:

[image]

```
Which of the above shown topologies are better performance wise ? Also, How should I decide which topology is running better than the other , seeing the bolts data ?
```

well let them run for a longer period of time. Both processed less than 1000 tuples, the size of the sample is too small. Ultimately the metric is the **"complete latency" on the spout and the number of failed tuples**.

Comment: Thanks,Nicely explained.